# Не билдится проект Android

Tags: android, gradle

Писал проект на windows. Перешел на Mac. Скинул проект на флэшку. Перекинул на мак. Начинаю собирать и вылетают такие ошибки. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Build -> Rebuild Project_ пробовали? Если не поможет, то _File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart_

Comment: Сейчас попробую. А что выбрать Just Restart или Restart and invalidate

Comment: _Restart and invalidate_

Comment: Бесполезно. Что ещё можно попробовать?

Comment: cmd + shift + f, и попробовать поискать attr/font, может откуда то залез

Comment: А вообще clean - rebuild обычно спасает

Comment: А что вводить то?

Comment: Попробуйте clean сначала, а потом уже будете поиском

Comment: Клин запускает градл и в итоге эти же ошибки вылетают

Comment: Хммм, это плохо. В поиск я бы ввел attr/font, а еще можно в разных вариациях просто font поискать, но подозреваю результатов будет очень много. Ищем по большому счету два файла, в которых этот аттр объявлен. Мб ещё вариант, что какие то из ваших депенденси за собой это тянут, тогда гуглите, возможно ли это в принципе и как ресурсы заэксклюдить

Comment: а если попробовать удалить этот файл?

Comment: я понял в чем дело. Удалите .gradle/caches и всё будет хорошо)

Comment: а где находится этот файл?

Comment: Ну как же, у вас в ошибке путь к нему, и это папка, а не файл. Users/administrator/.gradle/caches

Comment: как все непривычно. не могу найти

Comment: скорее всего папка .gradle скрытая, я не помню, как на маке их показывать, но погуглите

Comment: я так понял она в папке проекта находится?

Comment: нет, в папке юзера, на юниксовых системах папка юзера корневая, в ней же downloads, documents,music и всякое такое. В этой же папке и .gradle

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда переходил с 2.3 на 3.0 версии `Android Studio`. В моем проекте был кастомный атрибут `font`, который конфликтовал с добавленным аттрибутом с таким же именем в новой версии `API`. Переименовав в классах, `attr.xml` файле и в `styles.xml`  `font` на другое имя (`myfont`, например) компиляция прошла успешно. Судя по логам у Вас аналогичная ошибка.

Comment: а каким образом это делается?

Comment: @PavelVorobyov в `values/attrs.xml` (если такой файл вы вносили) вы могли добавить собственный аттрибут шрифта. http://joxi.ru/zANMkvQSlgREP2 если есть такое и у вас `font` в аттрибуте, то значит проблема именно в этом. Меняете в этом файле, а потом в классах где этот аттрибут вызывался http://joxi.ru/n2YLOjYCjONY7m

Comment: а можно как-то этот файл где дубликаты удалить. так как при билде он открывается. этих атрибутов около 50-60 которые дублируются.

Comment: @PavelVorobyov Не хочу никого обидеть, но конфликт явно ежду закешированным файлом гредла и файлом проекта, поэтому надо просто почистить кеш

Comment: как бы еще найти))) на маке

Comment: у вас не будет возможности в скуп выйти

Comment: было бы неплохо

Comment: @PavelVorobyov burnix13

Comment: @PavelVorobyov напишите мне в скайп alesetar, только не звоните, я не люблю голосом разговаривать